# path to adjacency matrix in networkx

Tags: python, matrix, networkx

I'm trying to convert paths in graphs in into adjacency matrix using the networkx library. 
I can convert a whole graph into an adjacency matrix:

```
>>>import networkx as nx
>>>DG=nx.DiGraph()
>>>DG.add_edges_from([(1,2), (2,3),(1,3)])
>>>nx.to_numpy_matrix(DG)
....matrix([[ 0.,  1.,  1.],
    [ 0.,  0.,  1.],
    [ 0.,  0.,  0.]])
```

However, after I find all simple paths from node 1 to node 3:

```
>>>list(nx.all_simple_paths(DG,1,3))
....[[1, 2, 3], [1, 3]]
```

I'm unable to turn them into an adjacency matrix. 
I want to be able to choose a path and turn it into an adjacency matrix,
for example, the second path should return:

```
....matrix([[ 0.,  0.,  1.],
    [ 0.,  0.,  0.],
    [ 0.,  0.,  0.]])
```

Comment: what would be the desired result for path `[1,2,3]`?

Comment: [[0.,1.,0.],[0.,0.,1.],[0.,0.,0.]]

Comment: try defining all the nodes prior to defining edges. This way you can take `[1,2,3]`, split them into a list of tuples like [(1,2),(2,3)] and use `nx.to_numpy_matrix()` to get the adjacency matrix

Comment: else it wont handle for cases like `[1,3]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not an adjacency matrix. But you can easily build it yourself as follows:

```
import networkx as nx
import numpy as np

DG=nx.DiGraph()
DG.add_edges_from([(1,2), (2,3),(1,3)])
paths = list(nx.all_simple_paths(DG,1,3))

for path in paths:
    matrix = np.matrix(np.zeros((len(DG), len(DG))))
    for i in range(len(path)-1):
        matrix[path[i]-1], path[i+1]-1] = 1  # edit: credits to @Joel
    print(matrix)
```

output:

```
[[ 0.  1.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  1.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.]]
[[ 0.  0.  1.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.]]
```

Comment: should it be `matrix[path[i]-1, path[i+1]-1] = 1`?